# Certain Drush commands not available

Tags: drush

I'm no newbie to using Drush, but I'm working on a "legacy" install that I have a feeling hasn't been set up right.

This is the relevant (my purposes) part of the `drush` output. I can see the commands I'm trying to work with listed.

> SQL commands: (sql) sql-cli (sqlc)        Open a SQL command-line
>   interface using Drupal's    credentials.             sql-connect
>   A string for connecting to the DB.
>   sql-create            Create a database.
>   sql-drop              Drop all tables in a given database.
>   sql-dump              Exports the Drupal DB as SQL using mysqldump or
>   equivalent.               sql-query (sqlq)      Execute a query
>   against the site database.                                sql-sync
>   Copy and import source database to target database. Transfers via
>   rsync.

The only commands that work are `sql-cli` and `sql-dump`, though.

This is the output from running `drush sql-load --help`.

> The drush command 'sql-load' could not be found.  Run `drush
>   cache-clear drush` to clear the commandfile cache if you have
>   installed new extensions.

For reference I'm using drush 5.7.  And yes, I have run `drush cc drush` to no avail.

I'm leaning towards gutting out this version of drush and starting from scratch, as it was not built system-wide and I had to add a custom PATH variable in order to find drush, but if anyone has any insight I would love to hear it.

EDIT: Providing more information for everyone.  The OS is Ubuntu 12.04, fairly standard Apache2 with Amazon RDS dbs.  The sad thing is, I have no reference for how it was initially installed.  `which drush` outputs `/usr/bin/drush` but it also exists in `/var/www/<webroot>/bin/drush`, which is the version I've been using and that is causing issues.  My standard MO is to install drush as an Ubuntu package, and I've never had any issues that way.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how drush was installed? And from which folder are you issuing these commands? Are you in the apache root (/var/www/html)?

Comment: I have drush installed on a whole bunch of servers git git.  sql-load isn't a command on any of them.  5.7 isn't terribly behind the latest kosher tag (7.x-5.9).  What does drush st do?

Comment: Just FYI, drush sql-load was a command in Drush 2.  It was replaced by sql-sync in Drush 3.

Comment: Now this is insightful.  Does Drush 3 still list deprecated commands when invoked without arguments? Is there any way to tell if I'm using Drush 2 vs. Drush 3?

`bin/drush sql-sync` appears to work, although I have no aliases set up with it yet to truly test it.

Comment: @PatrickBurch `drush --version`

Comment: @Clive I mentioned in my original post the drush version is 5.7.  Thanks!